# Request JSONP with text/plain MIME Type

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to use JSONP to request a feed on another domain.  I know that the content type should be JSON or JavaScript, but it is text/plain and I don't have control over the server so I can't change the header.  How can I get an AJAX call to work?

Here is what I have so far -

```
function asdf() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://example.com/path/to/sharepoint/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/TestCalendar/$count",
        jsonp: "callback",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        contentType: "text/plain",

        // work with the response
        success: function( response ) {
            console.log( response ); // server response
        }
    });
}
```

If I just try a regular request, obviously I just get a CORS error.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/path/to/sharepoint/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/TestCalendar/$count. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute directly your URL in a browser to be sure that all is working fine
After that, try with this JQuery configuration:

```
$.ajax({
        url        : "YOUR_URL",
        dataType   : 'jsonp',
        crossDomain: true,
        type       : 'POST',
        timeout    : 30000, // in milli seconds
        cache      : false
        success:function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
```